# How to disable click event on leaflet map only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have created the `button` to open the bootstrap modal inside my leaflet `map` id as follows,

```html
<div id='map'> 
  <div id="bootstrapModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#baseLayerModal">Click</div>
</div>
```

When I click on a map, I added the function to add the marker and open the popup as below,

```js
map.on('click', function(e) {
    const latLng = [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng];
    marker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("this is popup").openPopup();
}
```

But when I click my `button`, it opens both the bootstrap modal and leaflet popup. But I only want to open the bootstrap modal when the user clicks the `button`. To block this issue, I tried the following method,

```js
$(".bootstrapModalBtn").on("click", L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
```

After adding the last section, I was unable to get the bootstrap modal and leaflet popup. My question is, how to disable the click event only from the map for the `button`?

**PS:** I also tried the `map.off('click')` method. But I was unable to reactivate the click event after setting `map.off('click')`,

```js
$(".bootstrapModalBtn").on("click", map.off('click');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems that is only a typo, your *bootstrapModalBtn* element is not selected.

Replace `.` with `#` in your jQuery selector (*id* selector, not *class*). Or replace `id="bootstrapModalBtn"` with `class="bootstrapModalBtn"`.

Then, as you said, use `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
$("#bootstrapModalBtn").on("click", (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();

    /* open your modal here */
});
```

Comment: Thank you for addressing the issue. `e.preventDefault()` works for me